# C++ Map with vector as key. How to make it so vector order doesn't matter?

Tags: c++, containers, stdvector, stdmap, unordered

I have a map that takes a vector of ints as a key. I initialise the map with a key vector of values `{1, 2, 3}`

```
typedef std::map<std::vector<int>, std::string> VectorMap;
VectorMap vectorMap;
vectorMap[std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}] = "test";
```

Then I use the count method to display if the entry in VectorMap can be found by using a vector of `{1, 2, 3}` as the key.

```
std::cout << "count: " << vectorMap.count(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}) << std::endl;
```

This returns the correct count.

> count: 1

However I want to make it so the order of the ints in the vector does not matter. So I attempt the same as above but with the vector contents flipped i.e. `{3, 2, 1}`

```
std::cout << "count: " << vectorMap.count(std::vector<int>{3, 2, 1}) << std::endl;
```

This returns a count of 0.

> count : 0

I want to make it so that the vector comparison does not matter about the order of the contents, just if the contents are the same.

```
{1, 2, 3} count: 1
{3, 2, 1} count: 1
{1, 2} count: 0
{1, 2, 3, 4} count : 0
```

How can I achieve this? Should I use a different container altogether instead of std::vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If order of elements in the key doesn't matter, then you probably can use std::set (if all elements are supposed to be unique) or std::multiset, if key can have duplicate elements. I.e. `std::map<std::set<int>, std::string>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain those types you can do it by defining a custom orderless comparator for you map, like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct VectorComparatorOrderless
{
    bool operator()(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b)const // comparator a < b
    {
        if (a.size() < b.size()) return true;
        if (a.size() > b.size()) return false;

        return !std::all_of(a.cbegin(), a.cend(),
            [&](const int& elementOfVectorA) -> bool
            {
                return std::find(b.cbegin(), b.cend(), elementOfVectorA) != b.cend();
            }
        );
    }
};

typedef std::map<std::vector<int>, std::string, VectorComparatorOrderless> VectorMap;

int main()
{

    VectorMap vectorMap;

    vectorMap[std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}] = "test";

    std::cout << "count: " << vectorMap.count(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "count: " << vectorMap.count(std::vector<int>{3, 2, 1}) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "count: " << vectorMap.count(std::vector<int>{2, 3, 1}) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "count: " << vectorMap.count(std::vector<int>{2, 3}) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "count: " << vectorMap.count(std::vector<int>{2}) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "count: " << vectorMap.count(std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4}) << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

output:

```
count: 1
count: 1
count: 1
count: 0
count: 0
count: 0
```